# Encoding Issue When Attempting to Convert Hindi Script PDF to CSV in Python

Tags: python, pdf-scraping, tabula-py

I'm currently attempting to convert a PDF file containing Hindi Devanagari script to a CSV file using the fitz library in Python, but when I read in the text I encounter a strange encoding issue.

Here is a page from the PDF:

[Page From Hindi Script PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq1EX.png)

I am using the following code to read in the text:

```
import fitz
from indic_transliteration import sanscript
from indic_transliteration.sanscript import transliterate

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file):
    text = ""
    with fitz.open(pdf_file) as pdf_document:
        for page_num in range(len(pdf_document)):
            page = pdf_document.load_page(page_num)
            text += page.get_text()
    return text

def devanagari_to_roman(text):
    return transliterate(text, sanscript.DEVANAGARI, sanscript.ITRANS)

def main():
    pdf_file = 'data/agra_2010.pdf'  
    extracted_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file)
    roman_text = devanagari_to_roman(extracted_text)
    print(roman_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But here is an example of how the Hindi text appears in the output:

```
òû£û™û
òû£û™û
òû£û™û
òû£û™û
ftys dk uke&
ftys dk dksM &
```

I encounter the same issue when using the tabula function read_pdf, so this isn't simply an issue with the library I'm using. I would like to maintain the Hindi script in my output. Please let me know if you have any solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using other libraries?

Comment: It would appear that the PDF is using two legacy fonts, each using a different encoding. It isn't a problem with the PDF library per se, more of an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply that corrupt file, but it is not hard to find a very similar corruption on the web.

[image]

That is an everyday problem, a non-standard font has been used so the numbers on the surface do not match the ink. I have selected the "fuok" part. And we see the Devanagari ink is top left stored as a `f`. 2nd row down & 3rd from left is the binary `u` and its Devanagari ink appearance etc.

The good news is that the Latin fonts are correctly embedded. Also this should be one of the easier to fix types, since it seems there are few or no repeats.

Bad news is that is a darn slow manual haul, to verify two full alphabets of mapping, and you may still finish with rubbish.

Let's start with the keycode for `f` [image] = "U+093F: DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN I" `ि` so we need to re-map that key then VA NA  (I probably have those wrong ?).

Certainly some will look better but when replacing characters in that fashion they usually end up worse.

So forget editing inside PDF by simple find and replace unless you want to retype the lot. Due to the BiDi overlay, all the **letter positions will be corrupted** without additional kerning. Forgive my lack of correctly matching a character or two here (on the plain text at right) we see the Hindi characters will not be overlaid as expected.

[image]

It is simpler to use the plain text by find and replace using a similar but binary numerically programmable means using Devanagari inside a word processor.

So import into MS Word and use find and replace Hindi style it will be better. **Thus, a VBA programming solution is required.**

[image]

Comment: Since its an encoding issue, and alternative approach is to write a codec for the encoding being used.

Comment: Actually there are no bidi issues, and the encoding will be a visual encoding. It is true that there is a remapping of visual to logical layout during the encoding conversion. Which is why an encoding conversion is the better approach that substitution or remapping.

Comment: The complexity is that it appears two seperate legacy encodings are being used. Which would require conversion based on font rendering runs. Easier doing that within Word than as plaintext within Python.

Comment: ToUnicode mappings are relatively pointless, they only work with the simplest fonts. They can not support complex script rendering or advanced Opentype rendering. One of the reasons Actual text attributes where introduced for tagged PDFs. Best approach is to convert to word then do encoding conversion on font runs from within word. The tolls exist. But that is dependant on the glyph assignments not being warped during font sub setting.

Comment: There are two fonts used in PDF. The first font contains normal ASCII (Latin) in G0, and has Devanagari in G1. The second font has Devanagari in G0.

Comment: Using the PDF you supplied, the fonts are not corrupted to ANSII range, there are two legacy (pre-Unicode) Devanagari fonts embedded in the PDF. One appears to be a font called Arjun: for example `in dh vkj{k.k Js.kh` converted to Unicode is `पद की आरक्षण श्रेणी`, `firk@ifr dk uke` = `पिता/पति का नाम`, etc. Still trying to identify the second font.

Comment: The second font, at a guess is one of the Suchi Dev fonts.

Comment: If it is a TTE, TTE's handle distinct isolated glyphs, and and the TTE would be paired with a corresponding TTF file, if I understand the format properly.